# Minimum of a function that is an expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. Define a function $f$ by 
>   $$f(t)=E[(X+tY)^2]$$
>   Find the value $t$ that minimizes $f(t)$ in terms of $E(X^2),E(Y^2),$ and 
>   $E(XY)$. Evaluate the function at this value $t$ and show that 
>   $[E(XY)]^2\leq E(X^2)E(Y^2)$?

So, I expanded the expectation

1. $f(t)=E[X^2+2tXY+t^2Y^2]=E[X^2]+2tE[XY]+t^2E[Y^2]$
2. $f'(t)=2E[XY]+2tE[Y^2]=0 \Rightarrow t=-\dfrac{E[XY]}{E[Y^2]}$
3. $f''(t)=2>0$ and thus the $t$ value is at a minimum.

Evaluating $f$ at this $t$ gives
\begin{align*}
f\left(-\dfrac{E[XY]}{E[Y^2]}\right)&=E[X^2]+2\left(
-\dfrac{E[XY]}{E[Y^2]}\right)E[XY]+\left(-\dfrac{E[XY]}{E[Y^2]}\right)^2E[Y^2]\\
&=E[X^2]-\dfrac{E[XY]^2}{E[Y^2]}
\end{align*}
I think I'm close, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: It seems like your done here. To get your inequality just use Cauchy-Scwartz.

Comment: This is a good exercise and your work is flawless.  All you needed was that one last step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close indeed. Note that $f(t)$ is always non-negative by definition, since it is the expectation of a squared expression (the term inside $E$ in the definition of $f$ is always non-negative). This means that $0\le f(t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$, so in particular $$
0\le f\left(-\dfrac{E[XY]}{E[Y^2]}\right)=E[X^2]-\dfrac{E[XY]^2}{E[Y^2]} \implies E[XY]^2\le E[X^2]E[Y^2]$$ (Note, also that $E[Y^2]\ge 0$ so when we multiplied both sides with it, the direction of $\ge$ did not change.)